# Resolve objects in array from observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, frontend, ag-grid, rxjs-observables

I have a question regarding to resolving observables in an array. (Using Angular 11)

First, I want to describe the scenario. Let's assume we have a component, with a ag-grid

`table.component.html`

```
    <ag-grid-angular
      [rowData]="data"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

where rowData is something like

```
[
  {id:0, user: 'userName1', valueBefore: 1, valueAfter:2},
  {id:1, user: 'userName1', valueBefore: 3, valueAfter:4},
  ...
]
```

Nothing fancy yet - however, the ids of `valueBefore` and `valueAfter` need to be resolved to their names. For that, a http request must be done, e.g. `HTTP GET /name/1` which returns `{id:1, name: 'one'}`

Unfortunately, I don't see a nice way to do it.

I see a solution like fetching all the names first. Then, update the `rowData` object in one brush so the table is only rerendered once.
But then I'd have to maintain an array of `id/name` pairs which I don't like.

I don't know if I'm missing some features that I could use here or so.

Do you have an idea? How would you solve that problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If possible get those data with join query in Backend while fetching the rowData in first place. 
I would suggest not to make API calls to to fetch name of every single user in the list. For ex.: If there are 100 rows in your rowData you will end up making 200 API calls for valueBefore and valueAfter in your application. Thats just to render a grid. Not good.

Comment: You should be able to pre-fetch all names, as you suggest, and rebuild your rowData to contain a valueBefore/valueAfter of type "{ id: number, name: string }". No need to manage an external pair array. I have not worked with ag-grid, but I am pretty sure it can bind to properties of complex objects (e.g. valueBefore.name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's easy with RxJS to maintain loaded values. Just add this code to component:

```
    cacheTimeout = 60 * 1000;
    valueCache = new Map<number, Observable<string>>();
    getValue$ = (id: number) => {
      if (!this.cache.get(id)) {
        this.cache.set(id, this.http.get('/name/'+id.toString()).pipe(
          map(result => result.name),
          publishReplay(1, this.cacheTimeout),
          refCount(),
          take(1),
        ));
      }
      return cache.get(id);
    }
```

and use `getValue$(id) | async` inside your template